# gpupdate / force not has default timeout limitation 600 seconds?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, group-policy

We are using GPUpdate /force, we find sometimes it will take over 30 minutes in our customer's azure VM. But we can see the MS document mentioned has a default wait time of 600 seconds. Can anyone help with this? why it takes over the default timeout limitation? will it only works when we follow "/wait" behind the command?
I didn't have a domain that can let me test to run gpupdate that can take over 600 seconds.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50ZkL.png)

Comment: How are you measuring the execution time of `gpupdate`?

Comment: I have a feeling that one of your policies is taking a long time to apply. If you try to `/target` only the user or computer, does one take longer than the other?

Comment: I measuring by Get-Date, before and after execute the gpupdate, some customers execution time would more than the default time 10 minutes. some customers executed the "gpupdate /force" for about 30 minutes.